# how can I get data from multiple related tables in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have three tables: events - admins - dependencies
The relationship between them is the following:
a dependency has many admins, an admin has many events

like that: 
[image]

I'm trying to show the name of the dependency to which the admin that created the event belongs.
How could I bring data with Laravel from this three tables?

controller:

```
class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    public function evento($slug){
        $event = Event::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        return view('evento', compact('event'));
    }
```

Event model:

```
class Event extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'admin_id', 'place_id', 'name', 'slug', 'excerpt', 'body', 'status', 'file'
    ];

    public function admins(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Admin', 'admin_id');
    }
```

Admin model:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'cargo', 'dependence_id'
    ];

    public function dependencyAdmin(){
            return $this->belongsTo(Dependence::class);
        }
```

Dependence Model:

```
class Dependence extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'slug'
    ];

    public function adminsDependence(){
        return $this->hasMany(Admin::class);
    }
```

So I try to show it in the view, but it does not work:

```
 <div class="panel-heading"> 
                Dependencia: 
                <a href="#">{{$event->admins->dependencyAdmin->name}}</a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Do you get an error or just null?

Comment: the error is: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: That code is correct, I think some objects just don't have any data to load and $event->admins->dependencyAdmin results in null. Try this {{$event->admins->dependencyAdmin->name ?? "Empty"}} and see what happens.

Comment: You are not using the eloquent naming conventions, that's probably the problem. `dependencyAdmin`: `$this->belongsTo(Dependence::class, 'dependence_id')` https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse. Or rename `dependencyAdmin` to `dependence`. The same goes with `adminsDependence`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're only retrieving the event model without loading the relationship. See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) for more explanation

```
$event = Event::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$eventAdmins = $event->admins()->get();
$eventAdminDependency = $eventAdmins->dependencyAdmin()->get();
```

Comment: There's no need for that, eloquent will load them in demand by calling the relationship without the parenthesis. I think the relationships is just empty.